# How to set autolayout on label which shows at the top if Image is not displayed?

Tags: ios, sdk, ios-autolayout

I have an view in which at the top of view I had put Image view if the post has "Image", It displays image, but if post has no image then it can't.

Now I want to set that If there is no Image then Label which is reside at the bottom of image view, comes at the top of view. So, that it looks perfect.

**Here is scenario, Please look into it.**

```
> Image View | Label | Label | Label | Label | and so on...
```

Now, If there is no Image then My View is

```
>            | Label | Label | Label | Label | and so on...
```

But, I want to remove this extra space using Autolayout so, my view will look like this

```
> | Label | Label | Label | Label | and so on...
```

How can I set this using **Autolayout**.

Please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

please do as shown in below screen shots hope it will help you

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey @Pritesh, there is a same scenario with my table view, I want that If there is an Image in table cell then the width of label remaining same, and If there is no image then width of label will increase and cover the extra space. What should I do ?

Comment: same as above , but you just need to bind the outlet for image width constrain and keep width constant priority (750)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to show imageView if there is any image other wise you have to show UiLabel.You can do this by make a check in if condition that if there is image make UIImageview hidden to false and UIlabel hidden to true.And reverse in else condition.hope this work for you.If you do not got this,Please tell me I will help you.Thanks

Comment: No, Actually Label Has value every time, So Label will be display every time, but image may be not, So I want to set that if there is no image then Label will display at the top using Autolayout.

Comment: then you can place a image view and then label in middle of uiimageview,and give constraint to label with uiimageview like centerX and centerY .I am not getting u proper.You can send me sample at tarunsachdeva001@gmail.com

Comment: Okay I got what u actually want.Now The first thing is that u have to set the constraint programmatically based on the condition if image is there or not.And other solution not the best that u can make two luiview's one with image view and other is without image view,and based on the condition show and hide the uiview.:)

Comment: @AartiOza I got your issue and also know how to resolve it,,but unable to tell u haw to do. ...Okay...Simple take 2 subview on your main uiview.On Make one subview with ur image view and all other labels,and make other subview with only labels on that.Place them on top on main view where u want those.One upon other,Now in coding hide and show subview based on condition that if image is there or not......

Comment: I got my solution in Pritesh's anwer, Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Make the constraint to the first label a property in ur class. And then in ur code u can update the constraint's property called "constant" accordingly. Like if (imageIsPresent) then myConstraint.constant=0 else my constraint.constant=someValue

Not sure but it should work.